# Does an extrovert have an advantage over an introvert on the WAIS-IV Arithmetic subtest?

Tags: memory, iq

I guess yes, because an extrovert gets more exposure to verbal conversation and then is more able to remember what the proctor said on the Arithmetic subtest. However, someone else said that this is not true and that attention control stays constant despite having more exposure to verbal conversations. Who is correct?

Would the arithmetic subtest score be deflated for someone who doesn't go out and speak to others as much as the average person?

The arithmetic subtest consists of spoken math word problems and the testee answers the proctor in 30 seconds with a repeat of the question if the testee asks. This is a WMI subtest on the WAIS IV.